# Writing a Hypervisor?

Tags: c++, hypervisor

I am researching ideas for a PhD project.

One of my thoughts is writing a hypervisor (or bare metal) (?) so I could run multiple OS's without use of a true host operating system. Example I get a menu of some type of options to start operating systems, view what the 'console' of what is going on in an OS that is already running. Reboot OS's, install a new one, etc.

So no host OS, just a small app that controls everything.

Conceptually how does one think about doing this?

I have a MacBook. I should be able to modify what the EFI boots. Maybe start with a very minimal Linux LIve implementation and scale it really, really far back?

Is it possible to use Darwin and scale it very far back?

Comment: As a PhD project, what is original and new about your idea?

Comment: Considering that several of these have already been written (Xen, L4 are hypervisors if I am not mistaken), would it make a good PhD topic? You could use your own hypervisor as the context in which to experiment with new techniques that can be the topic of a PhD, but this kind of indirect task is better left to permanent researchers (a PhD lasts a short time and should be more focused than that).

Comment: @jball. There is more to it that I see as far as load balancing and scaling, but I can't think about that until I have the core concepts working.

Comment: @Pascal - well also, I would like to run a hypervisor on my MacBook so I can run a number of OS's at one time.

Comment: Have you looked at existing solutions? KVM + Qemu comes to mind, Xen was already mentioned - they are all mature projects. And what do you mean by "no host OS, just a small app that controls everything"? You *need* the host OS (you can strip it down a lot, but it's an OS nevertheless).

Comment: @igor - Linux-KVM looks interesting, I had not heard of it.

Comment: VMware ESX (IIRC that's the one) seems to be exactly what you are trying to achieve - "something" that you can boot your host with and quickly set up virtual guests. Last one project, I'd like to mention is OpenVZ - it's definitely worth checking out, as it's concept is different than the other hypervisors (if you could call it that). As you can see, there are many solutions available, and if yours doesn't provide anything innovative (that's the point of the PhD, right?), then I'd recommend something else - maybe some cool usage of the virtualization technology, like they did with OpenVZ?

Comment: @ator What you ended up choosing for your PhD project?

Answer (score 4):

Your idea as stated is not an original contribution to the science.

My advice is to review Xen and the general hypervisor literature, dating back to the '60s & 
'70s when IBM invented it.

I'm certain there is room for improvement and original ideas there.

In terms of actually writing a hypervisor, you should review Wikipedia first, as it gives a good brief on virtualization.

Here is a historical summary, including some seminal citations: http://www.kernelthread.com/publications/virtualization/. Note the first citation is from 1959!

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling back an existing OS to develop a hypervisor seems an unlikely approach.

Definitely have a look at some of the existing open source hypervisor project out there.
If you are interesting in reading about how they work and how you might approach writing
one then you could try:

Virtual Machines by Smith & Mair.
The Definitive Guide to the Xen Hypervisor by Chisnall.

If you are going to write it from scratch, and you are targeting the x86 family of processors then you are going to have to get your hands dirty with virtualization instructions (eg. Intel VT-x). And this will be with pure assembly language, or at best inline assembly. You are talking real low level stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling back an existing desktop/server OS seems like a poor choice.  OTOH, rather than redo everything, it may be useful to start with an embedded RTOS such as ecos or L4 to draw some features from.  Additionally, some code could possibly be re-used from QEMU.

If I were doing it, I would focus on hardware virtualization using VT-x and AMD-V ignore dynamic recompilation (unless was to be the focus of your work).

Also, it seems to me that it would be a good idea to already be able to write operating systems enough to make some small test operating systems that can boot on bare hardware to use for testing the hypervisor under development.

BTW, if scaling back an existing OS was a good strategy, I think it would work best on Linux or one of the major BSDs.  Using Darwin is likely asking for pain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in computer communication and hypervisiors what about cross OS communication [it would be cheaper than trying to connect via normal TCP/IP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

ESX is essentially a scaled-back Linux install - with a host of other goodies added: so your basic premise is decent.

However, for a PhD project, it sounds too broad: you should focus on something smaller.